# Вопросы по книге

Tags: java

В книге по Java написано:

1. **У меня может быть много методов**.

   **Ответ:** Класс, объект.

   Класс я понимаю, у класса может быть много методов ибо они там находятся, а как у объекта? У объекта потому что это экземпляр класса и методы косвенно к нему тоже относятся? Ну мол если у класса есть, то и у объекта потому что это экземпляр класса?
2. **Я могу вести себя по-разному**.

   **Ответ:** Класс, объект.

   Не очень понимаю как класс может себя вести по разному. Объект вызывает разные методы и в этом и заключается его: **вести себя по разному?**
3. **Я обитаю в куче**.

   **Ответ:** объект.

   Вот здесь если можно распишите по подробнее пожалуйста. Не очень понимаю почему объект, раз объект то почему тогда не классы?

**Заранее благодарю за помощь!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Да. Раз у класса много методов, то и у его экземпляра тоже.
2. Неоднозначно. Классы, в целом, не могут себя вести никак, и состояния нет у них. А вот у [объектов есть](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html).
3. Не до конца верно. Метаданные классов, к примеру, тоже в куче обитают. Про объекты https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf. Все экземпляры класса в хипе:

   > The Java Virtual Machine has a heap that is shared among all Java Virtual Machinethreads.  The  heap  is  the  run-time  data  area  from  which  memory  for  all  classinstances and arrays is allocated.

Comment: Можно вкратце про метаданные?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4. В PermGen для Java <7 и MetaSpace для Java 8+. Поля, методы, константы.

Comment: Извините последний вопрос, в переводе как я понял в куче могут храниться экземпляры и массивы классов?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван экземпляры и массивы вроде как всегда в куче создаются.

Comment: А что еще? Можете перечислить? Получается всё то, что мы пишем new создаются в куче?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван я с Java давно не работаю. Многие вещи могут отличаться в зависимости от JVM. Лучше смотреть, как это происходит в той jvm, под которую вы пишите.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы все правильно поняли. У класса продекларированы методы, а объект является представителем класса, то есть имеет те же методы (public разумеется)
2. Есть такое понятие, как полиморфизм. Думаю речь идет о том, что у одного класса может быть несколько реализаций. Пример

   ```
   public class Demo {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Animal animal1 = new Dog();
           Animal animal2 = new Cat();
           animal1.sound();
           animal2.sound();
       }
   }
   class Animal {
       void sound() {
           System.out.println("я животное");
       }
   }
   class Dog extends Animal {
       void sound() {
           System.out.println("Гав");
       }
   }
   class Cat extends Animal {
       void sound() {
           System.out.println("Мяу");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Это игра слов. Все объекты находятся в области памяти JVM, которая называется heap (русск. "куча")